# Starting a new project, how to setup UTC time correctly in java with hibernate and mysql

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

So I am starting a new project using java, hibernate and mysql (spring mvc).

At the database level, what column type should I use?

At the java level, I believe I should be using Joda time.

My users table will store their time offset, which I will then convert/format at the UI level using the UTC value from the database.

With hibernate, do I really need that joda time hibernate plugin or is adding joda time enough?

Can someone tell me what methods I will be needing, or an article that goes over things with source code?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may define your column in database as [TIMESTAMP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html) and map in Hibernate using `TimeStamp` object.

Use `SimpleDateFormat` in Java side to get the date time string in `UTC` as below:

```
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/DD/yyyy hh:mm a");
    formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    Date date = new Date(timeStamp.getTime());  
    String dateString = formatter.format(date);
    System.out.println(dateString);
```

Answer (score 0):

At database level you can use datetime or timestamp (in MySQL) as column type. In Java you should use java.sql.Timestamp.

Joda time is possible but not absolutely necessary.

You can store the database time values either as UTC or as local time. I highly recommend to you using UTC. In the jdbc connect string (i. e. in hibernate.cfg.xml) you can define if the date always is in UTC or in local time, and JDBC does a time zone conversion if necessary (other time zone than UTC or local time can't be defined on JDBC level and will be much trouble if used).

When done like this you don't need special methods for the time zone conversion except them of the Java classes Calendar, Timezone and DateFormat.